# Sentence case without regular expressions

Tags: php, string

Is there a built-in php function, or a simple (efficient!) way to combine built-in functions, to give a string sentence case ("Sentence one. Sentence two.")?

PHP has similar built-in functions, but none that I can find for my it to my purposes:

`ucfirst(strtolower("SENTENCE ONE. AND HERE'S TWO."))` returns "Sentence one. and here's two."; `ucwords(strtolower("SENTENCE ONE. AND HERE'S TWO."))` "Sentence One. And Here's Two."

Comment: that is because it is syntactically easy to define what a word is, or what the first letter of a word is. it's actually not that easy to define what a sentence is without having a proper grammer for the language used. i'd suggest to just use regular expressions. they are reasonably fast so you don't have to worry.

Comment: You could always explode the string into an array at every full stop, run ucfirst on every array entry and then implode it. (If you really don't want to use Regex that is).

Comment: Don't underestimate the grammar difficulty alluded to by Basti. All the solutions so far will fail with proper names and acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sentence_case($str) {
   $cap = true;
   $ret='';
   for($x = 0; $x < strlen($str); $x++){
       $letter = substr($str, $x, 1);
       if($letter == "." || $letter == "!" || $letter == "?"){
           $cap = true;
       }elseif($letter != " " && $cap == true){
           $letter = strtoupper($letter);
           $cap = false;
       } 
       $ret .= $letter;
   }
   return $ret;
}
```

This will preserve existing proper noun capitals, acronyms and abbreviations.

Comment: A little late to the party :), but this works very well! It won't put an all-uppercase sentence into proper case, but this is the closest to my needs so I'm marking it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string on ".", then ucfirst each sentence.  Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
$sentences = explode(".",$paragraph);
$text = "";
foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
   $text .= ucfirst(strtolower($sentence)).".";
}
```

Comment: What happens if a sentence ends in a question or exclamation mark?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function sentenceCase($s){
    $str = strtolower($s);
    $cap = true;

    for($x = 0; $x < strlen($str); $x++){
        $letter = substr($str, $x, 1);
        if($letter == "." || $letter == "!" || $letter == "?"){
            $cap = true;
        }elseif($letter != " " && $cap == true){
            $letter = strtoupper($letter);
            $cap = false;
        }

        $ret .= $letter;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) Works with more than just periods as line endings.

Comment: This is what I was looking for; thanks. It's strange that this isn't a built-in function.

Comment: This does not handle acronyms e.g U.S. is converted to u.S.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution using [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split).  It will try to split sentences on `.` boundaries where there is one or more spaces after the period.
It is still pretty efficient, but arguably less so that it's explode counterpart.

```
<?php

$str = "SENTENCE ONE. AND HERE'S TWO.";

$sentences = preg_split('/(\.\s+)/', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

array_walk(&$sentences, create_function('&$val', '$val = ucfirst(strtolower($val));')); 

$str = implode('', $sentences);

echo $str;  // Sentence one. And here's two.
```

Answer (score 0):

Will work with new line breaks not only spaces.

```
function sentenceCase($text){

    $cap = true; $newText = '';

    for($x = 0; $x < strlen($text); $x++){

        $letter = substr($text, $x, 1);

        if($letter == '.' || $letter == '!' || $letter == '?' || $letter == "\n"){

            $cap = true;

        } elseif($letter != ' ' && $cap == true){

            $letter = strtoupper($letter);
            $cap = false;
        } 

        $newText .= $letter;
    }

    return $newText;
}
```